# SQL Most accurate way to calculate average increase

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Here is my problem..

I have a bunch of students with gpa scores for each quarter. I need to find the average increase over all quarters. What is the most accurate way to calculate this (taking zero into consideration)?

```
      studentID  q1     q2     q3     q4     avgIncrease
      123456789  3.41   2.86   3.29   3.86    ???
      234567891  1.23   2.54   1.25   4.0     ???
      345678912  2.01   1.23   3.12   3.57    ???
```

I've tried to code below but I come up with a different average than when i calculate it with excel.

```
SELECT     StudentId, q1, q2, q3, q4, 
(
    ((q2 - q1) / NULLIF (q1, 0)) + 
    ((q3 - q2) / NULLIF (q2, 0)) + 
    ((q4 - q3) / NULLIF (q3, 0))
)/3 AS avgIncrease
FROM  gpaTable
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: What does this return, and what does excel give you?

Comment: Accurate is one issue. if any of your q values is null, or any of q1 to q3 is zero avgincrease will be null. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this is a math problem.

Assuming q1=A, q2=B, q3=C and q4=D, then the difference is:

`B - A + C - B + D - C = - A + D = D - A`

Divide everything by 3 (3 differences), and you should get the same answer as Excel.

Therefore, the query should be something like:

```
SELECT StudentId, q1, q2, q3, q4, ((q4 -q1)/3) avgIncrease
FROM gpaTable
```

By the way, I am assuming in your example, that the `StudentId` is supposed to be different in the three lines above.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the arithmetic, this whole algorithm is flawed.

Consider a student whose scores change from 3 to 2 to 1 to 3. The average change by this reckoning is 0.389. What does that mean?

If the scores are 3, 2, 0.1, and 3, then the "average change" is 9.24.

3, 2, 0, 3 gives -0.444.

And in all cases the start and end values are the same and there has been no change. So it's not really an answer to the question, but there is no meaning to what you are trying to do.

To take an average change over the whole course you should just use (Q4 - Q1) / Q4 (with language dependent checks against division by zero of course).

Comment: That isn't true. If the student had (1,1,1,2) your formula would give an avg increase of 0.5=(2-1)/2. However, our three increases are 0, 0, and 1. So the average increase is 1/3.

Comment: He's basically right, it's just the formula needs slight modification: `(Q[Last] - Q1) / [# of quarters - 1]`. Using `1, 1, 1, 2` we get `(2 - 1) / 3` which is correct.

Comment: Oh: David's formula is correct if you are looking for **% increase**. My formula is correct if you are looking for **overall numeric increase**. This could be interpreted to mean **average numeric increase** but as he pointed out, averaging the increases, or adding them, or doing anything else to them will yield largely meaningless values.

Comment: I think that if you are looking at anything based on (Q4 - Q1) then dividing by the number of quarters is only relevant if you want to compare with Q3-Q1, Q4-Q2, etc.. Once you get into that area you're looking at some kind of second differential of the grade -- sounds like the old economists trick: "The debt isn't falling, in fact it's still getting bigger, but the rate at which the debt is increasing *is* falling".